# Dorpdownlist onchange in bootstrap modal not working

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, bootstrap-modal

I have a web form (.Net, C#) that has a jQuery data table. Each row has an "Edit" link that when clicked opens a Bootstrap modal and populates the controls. I have two drop downs in this modal: Area and District, where District is populated based on selected value of Area. To avoid modal closing on postback when Area is changed, I am trying to make ajax call to populate the District drop down.

Somehow, my onchange function does not get called. Also, i am not sure if entire setup is correct (apparently, not!)

This is what I have (watered down version):

HTML:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upAddEditModal" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="modal fade" id="editModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg fade in ui-draggable">
                <div class="modal-content">                    
                    <div class="modal-header ui-draggable-handle">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title"><span id="spnEditHeader"></span></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body"> 
                        <div class="row">               
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="ddlArea">Area</label>
                                    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" 
                                        ID="ddlArea" 
                                        ClientIDMode="Static" 
                                        CssClass="form-control" 
                                        DataTextField="AreaName" 
                                        DataValueField="AreaID" 
                                        AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="Select Area" Value="-1" />
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="ddlDistrict">District</label>
                                    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" 
                                        ID="ddlDistrict" 
                                        Enabled="false" 
                                        ClientIDMode="Static" 
                                        CssClass="form-control" 
                                        DataTextField="DistrictName" 
                                        DataValueField="DistrictID" 
                                        AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="Select District" Value="-1" />
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<script>
    $(function () {debugger
    $("#ddlArea").change(function () {
        var areaID = this.value;
        populateDistrictDDL(areaID);
    });

    function populateDistrictDDL(areaID) {debugger
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '<%= ResolveUrl("services/mpoo.asmx/GetDistrictsByAreaID") %>',
            data: areaID,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {debugger
                $("#ddlDistrict").empty().append($("<option></option>").val("-1").html("Select District"));
                $.each(msg.d, function () {
                    $("#ddlDistrict").append($("<option></option>").val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']));
                });
            },
            error: function (xhr) {debugger
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
         });
     };
    };
</script>

[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]

public string GetDistrictsByAreaID(string AreaID)
{
    string JSONresult = string.Empty;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(AreaID))
        return JSONresult;

    DataTable dt = BLL.GetDistrictsByAreaID(int.Parse(AreaID));
    JSONresult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);
    return JSONresult;
}
```

**Solution**:

Following changes are what made the issue to go away. It is partially based on Rahul's suggestion, which I marked as answer.

```
$(document).on('change', '#ddlArea', function () {
    var areaID = this.value;
    populateDistrictDDL(areaID);
});

function populateDistrictDDL(areaID) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: '<%= ResolveUrl("services/mpoo.asmx/GetDistrictsByAreaID") %>',
        cache: false,
        data: JSON.stringify({ "AreaID": areaID }), <-- this was changed
    }).done(function (result) {
        $("#ddlDistrict").empty().append($("<option></option>").val("-1").html("Select District"));
        jResult = JSON.parse(result.d); <-- this was added
        $.each(jResult, function (val, txt) {
            $("#ddlDistrict").append($("<option></option>").val(null == txt.DistrictID ? '-1' : txt.DistrictID).html(txt.DistrictName)); <-- this was changed
        });
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        var errMsg = textStatus + ' - ' + errorThrown + '... Status: ' + jqXHR.status + ",  ResponseText: " + jqXHR.responseText;
    });
}
```

Comment: Do you need to run `$("#ddlArea").change()` on `document.ready`? Perhaps the control does not exist in the DOM when you try to bind the `onchange` event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your script is the issue try this

```
    <script>
       $(function(){
        $("#ddlArea").on('change',function () {
            var areaID = this.value;
            populateDistrictDDL(areaID);
        });

        function populateDistrictDDL(areaID) {debugger
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '<%= ResolveUrl("services/mpoo.asmx/GetDistrictsByAreaID") %>',
                data: areaID,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {debugger
                    $("#ddlDistrict").empty().append($("<option></option>").val("-1").html("Select District"));
                    $.each(msg.d, function () {
                        $("#ddlDistrict").append($("<option></option>").val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']));
                    });
                },
                error: function (xhr) {debugger
                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                }
             });
         };
});
</script>
```

and alsoe you can do like tis whch is more preferd

```
$(document).on('change','#ddArea',function(){
//your code
})
```

Comment: This is what I originally had. I added "debugger" to trace it and it would be hit on page load and then get stuck. The modal is to pop up when Edit link on data table row is clicked. I open the modal from code behind after populating it initially. So even with these changes, when I change the Area nothing happens. I updated the code based on your suggestion.

Comment: I updated the question, partially based on Rahul's answer, and added what solved the issue. I used the second part of Rahul's answer (using $(documeny).on(...))

Answer (score 0):

The simplieast way to do so is that

$('#editModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {

```
        $(document).on("change", "#ddArea", function (e) {

            var yourvar = this.value;

        });
```